# What login manager does Lubuntu use and how can I configure it?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, login-screen

Does Lubuntu use LXDM or SSDM? (I got this confusion by googling it. On some websites it said, it's LXDM and some said it's SSDM.)

I mainly want to customise the login screen, but I couldn't find the setting to do it.

Please suggest a graphical way to customise the login screen, mainly the wallpaper as 20.04's Lubuntu wallpaper is so ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lubuntu (*since 18.10 with [LXQt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXQt)*) uses SDDM.

Refer to the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html) for some configuration options.

The manual page will tell you

> There is no graphical application to do this currently.

(there is a means via KDE, but that will pull in a lot of KF5 & other Plasma components, which is why Lubuntu, which aims to be *light* (the L in LXQt) does not include that).

The default wallpaper *link* (`wall.png`) can be found in

`/usr/share/sddm/themes/lubuntu/`

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/usr/share/sddm/themes/lubuntu$   file wall.png
wall.png: symbolic link to ../../../lubuntu/wallpapers/lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png
```

so you can just change that too :)

Comment: Thanks it helped, just make the wallpaper changing process as it's provided in the manual, so that it's easy for other new users.